# Trying To Understand This Characteristic Velocity To Force Problem

Tags: rockets, rocket-equation

Having problems trying to solve part b of this problem.

Rocket Propulsion Elements 8th - Chapter 2

1. A jet of fluid hits a stationary flat plate in the manner shown below.

(a) If there is 50 kg of fluid flowing per minute at an absolute velocity of 200 m/sec, what will be the force on the plate?

(b) What will this force be when the plate moves in the direction of flow at u = 50 km/h? Explain the methodology.

Part A just involves plugging in mass flow rate, changing units to seconds, multiplying it by characteristic velocity to get force.

Part B, I have zero idea what's going on.  I thought it was a conservation of momentum problem, so I set up the problem as F = dm * v<sup>2</sup>, where v is 200-13.8 (13.8 being the change in speed in m/s as the plate moves away).  The problem is, I'm getting 155 N, whereas the correct answer is 144 N.

Comment: Not an answer: $F = dp/dt$. If $p = mv$ then $F= d(mv)/dt$, if $v$ ($dx/dt$) is constant then it's $F = v \ dm/dt$ Step 1 is figure out your flow in kg/m ($dm/dx$, kilograms per meter) in the initial case, then choose your velocity carefully, then use $dm/dt = dm/dx \times dx/dt$. hmm...  *I get  (200 - 13.899) * 0.8333 = 155.08 N also!* I get 144 only if the block moves at 100 km/hr.

Comment: The answer might be misprinted as well. Check with your classmates solution as well to verify the answer.

Comment: Just thinking of it another way: if the plate was moving 200 m/s the force would be zero N, when it's moving 0 m/s the force is 167 N. I see nothing to indicate the variation isn't linear so 155 N at a speed of 13.8 m/s makes sense to me. Incidentally in my tattered 4th edition it's  50 lb/s, 200 ft/s, and 50 mph. Plus they don't give the answers :)

Comment: @amar actually not reading this book for a class: My school doesn't have an aeronautics or astronautics program, so I'm going through the process of self-teaching myself.  Good to know I wasn't completely crazy in my calculation, thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 5):

The thing is that in the second case, the mass of the fluid hitting the plate in one second is *not the same* as in the first case. If the fluid flows at the rate $0.8333$ kg/s and speed $200$ m/s, then the linear density of the jet is $\frac{0.8333~ \text{kg/s}}{200~\text{m/s}}\approx 4.167~\text{g/m}$ (i.e., 1 meter of the jet contains 4.167 g of fluid). Relative to the plate, the fluid moves at approximately $186.1$ m/s, so the rate at which the fluid hits the plate is $4.167~\text{g/m}\cdot 186.1~\text{m/s} \approx 0.7755~\text{kg/s}$. Multiplying this rate by the velocity change of the fluid, we get the answer $0.7755~\text{kg/s}\cdot 186.1~\text{m/s}\approx 144.3~\text{N}$.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting the same answer as well (155N). I am using mass flow rate (0.83kg/s) multiplied by u (13.8m/s) to yield a 12N force and subtracting that from my original 167N force to yield 155N.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the answer to this problem;

m= 50kg/60sec = 0.833kg/sec

F= mass flow rate × v<sub>2</sub> (vehicle velocity)

F= 0.833 × 200m/sec

= 166.6N ( convert it to the nearest unit)

= 167N

Comment: The question the OP, and answerers, are primarily concerned with is part B, not part A.